# Event Listener in Google Charts based on Fusion Tables

Tags: javascript, events, google-visualization, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to use Google Fusion Tables with Google Charts to construct a table that would response to changes in a drop down menu.

I am following this example very closely:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/gviz_datatable

I can draw the table using data from the Fusion Tables. The table would response to the selection menu without issues.

I want to implement a selectHandler that would store the content of the row that is selected by the user. I am going to pass the content of the row to other functions, but I just couldn't get the selectHandler to work correctly.

```
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});

  function drawTable() {

      var query = "SELECT 'key', 'description' as Style, " +
              "'business_name' as Name, 'Rating' " +
              'FROM 15bCp26r1CDuN86Tu8hMOGRWlZwNI30Pl60srz9g';
      var vendors = document.getElementById('vendors').value;
      if (vendors) {
        query += " WHERE 'description' = '" + vendors + "'";
      }

      var queryText = encodeURIComponent(query);

      var gvizQuery = new google.visualization.Query(
        'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryText);

      gvizQuery.send(function(response) {
        var table = new google.visualization.Table(
          document.getElementById('visualization'));

        var data = response.getDataTable();

        table.draw(data, {
            showRowNumber: false,
            sortColumn: 3,
            sortAscending: false
        });

        google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', selectHandler);

        function selectHandler() {
            //alert("Selected");
            var selectedItem = table.getSelection()[0];
            var value = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, selectedItem.column);
            alert(value);
        }

    });      

  }
```

I am following the example pretty closely. The selectHandler does work. I can get an alert box to pop up when the user click on a row, but I can't store the content of the row to the variable value.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `var value` inside the `selectHandler` function, the scope of `value` is local to the function.  Once the function returns, the local variables are marked for garbage collection and made unaccessible.  If you want to store `value` longer-term, then it needs to be declared outside the local scope of `selectHandler`, like this:

```
var value;
function selectHandler () {...}
```

Incidentally, in the `selectHandler` function, you should be testing for the length of the selection, as it could be zero (which would throw an error in your code) or more than 1 (in which case you are not capturing all of the relevant information).  Try something like this:

```
function selectHandler() {
    var selection = table.getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

or this:

```
function selectHandler() {
    var selection = table.getSelection();
    for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
        // do something
    }
}
```